# Software (BornAgain) fails to compile, giving error "size_t not declared"

Tags: python, linux, cmake, fedora

I am honestly not sure where the issues lies and whether I should open an issue with the software project instead. But I need a program called BornAgain for work, and I need to compile it using CMake. I used to have it working nicely on Fedora 32, but when trying to install it on a fresher install with Fedora 34, I keep running into this issue. I've tried using different Python versions, but I am honestly not sure where to start troubleshooting here. The software is primarily written in c++ by the way if that helps.

I'm assuming it's some issue with different versions of dependencies that may not be compatible, but I cannot confirm this. The compilation ends with the following output:

```
[ 56%] Building CXX object Tests/UnitTests/Core/CMakeFiles/UnitTestCore.dir/Parameters/ParameterDistributionTest.cpp.o
In file included from /home/sjoerd/BA/bornagain/Tests/UnitTests/Core/Instrument/PrecomputedTest.cpp:1:
/home/sjoerd/BA/bornagain/Base/Math/Precomputed.h:29:11: error: ‘size_t’ has not been declared
   29 | template <size_t N> struct ReciprocalFactorial {
      |           ^~~~~~
/home/sjoerd/BA/bornagain/Base/Math/Precomputed.h:30:57: error: ‘N’ was not declared in this scope
   30 |     static constexpr double value = ReciprocalFactorial<N - 1>::value / N;
      |                                                         ^
/home/sjoerd/BA/bornagain/Base/Math/Precomputed.h:30:62: error: template argument 1 is invalid
   30 |     static constexpr double value = ReciprocalFactorial<N - 1>::value / N;
      |                                                              ^
/home/sjoerd/BA/bornagain/Base/Math/Precomputed.h:30:73: error: ‘N’ was not declared in this scope
   30 |     static constexpr double value = ReciprocalFactorial<N - 1>::value / N;
      |                                                                         ^
/home/sjoerd/BA/bornagain/Base/Math/Precomputed.h:37:21: error: ‘size_t’ has not been declared
   37 | template <template <size_t> class F, size_t... I>
      |                     ^~~~~~
/home/sjoerd/BA/bornagain/Base/Math/Precomputed.h:37:38: error: ‘size_t’ has not been declared
   37 | template <template <size_t> class F, size_t... I>
      |                                      ^~~~~~
/home/sjoerd/BA/bornagain/Base/Math/Precomputed.h:38:40: error: ‘I’ has not been declared
   38 | constexpr std::array<double, sizeof...(I)> generateArrayHelper(std::index_sequence<I...>)
      |                                        ^
/home/sjoerd/BA/bornagain/Base/Math/Precomputed.h:38:42: error: template argument 2 is invalid
   38 | constexpr std::array<double, sizeof...(I)> generateArrayHelper(std::index_sequence<I...>)
      |                                          ^
/home/sjoerd/BA/bornagain/Base/Math/Precomputed.h:38:84: error: ‘I’ was not declared in this scope
   38 | constexpr std::array<double, sizeof...(I)> generateArrayHelper(std::index_sequence<I...>)
      |                                                                                    ^
/home/sjoerd/BA/bornagain/Base/Math/Precomputed.h:38:85: error: expected parameter pack before ‘...’
   38 | constexpr std::array<double, sizeof...(I)> generateArrayHelper(std::index_sequence<I...>)
      |                                                                                     ^~~
/home/sjoerd/BA/bornagain/Base/Math/Precomputed.h:38:88: error: template argument 1 is invalid
   38 | constexpr std::array<double, sizeof...(I)> generateArrayHelper(std::index_sequence<I...>)
      |                                                                                        ^
/home/sjoerd/BA/bornagain/Base/Math/Precomputed.h: In function ‘constexpr int Math::internal::generateArrayHelper(int)’:
/home/sjoerd/BA/bornagain/Base/Math/Precomputed.h:40:15: error: ‘I’ was not declared in this scope
   40 |     return {F<I>::value...};
      |               ^
/home/sjoerd/BA/bornagain/Base/Math/Precomputed.h:40:16: error: template argument 1 is invalid
   40 |     return {F<I>::value...};
      |                ^
/home/sjoerd/BA/bornagain/Base/Math/Precomputed.h:40:27: error: cannot convert ‘<brace-enclosed initializer list>’ to ‘int’ in return
   40 |     return {F<I>::value...};
      |                           ^
/home/sjoerd/BA/bornagain/Base/Math/Precomputed.h: At global scope:
/home/sjoerd/BA/bornagain/Base/Math/Precomputed.h:48:11: error: ‘size_t’ has not been declared
   48 | template <size_t N, typename Indices = std::make_index_sequence<N>>
      |           ^~~~~~
/home/sjoerd/BA/bornagain/Base/Math/Precomputed.h:48:65: error: ‘N’ was not declared in this scope
   48 | template <size_t N, typename Indices = std::make_index_sequence<N>>
      |                                                                 ^
/home/sjoerd/BA/bornagain/Base/Math/Precomputed.h:48:65: error: template argument 1 is invalid
/home/sjoerd/BA/bornagain/Base/Math/Precomputed.h:49:30: error: ‘N’ was not declared in this scope
   49 | constexpr std::array<double, N> generateReciprocalFactorialArray()
      |                              ^
/home/sjoerd/BA/bornagain/Base/Math/Precomputed.h:49:31: error: template argument 2 is invalid
   49 | constexpr std::array<double, N> generateReciprocalFactorialArray()
      |                               ^
/home/sjoerd/BA/bornagain/Tests/UnitTests/Core/Instrument/PrecomputedTest.cpp:6:86: error: no matching function for call to ‘generateReciprocalFactorialArray<171>()’
    6 | constexpr auto ReciprocalFactorialArray = Math::generateReciprocalFactorialArray<171>();
      |                                           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~
In file included from /home/sjoerd/BA/bornagain/Tests/UnitTests/Core/Instrument/PrecomputedTest.cpp:1:
/home/sjoerd/BA/bornagain/Base/Math/Precomputed.h:49:33: note: candidate: ‘template<<declaration error>, class Indices> constexpr int Math::generateReciprocalFactorialArray()’
   49 | constexpr std::array<double, N> generateReciprocalFactorialArray()
      |                                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/sjoerd/BA/bornagain/Base/Math/Precomputed.h:49:33: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
make[2]: *** [Tests/UnitTests/Core/CMakeFiles/UnitTestCore.dir/build.make:664: Tests/UnitTests/Core/CMakeFiles/UnitTestCore.dir/Instrument/PrecomputedTest.cpp.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:2275: Tests/UnitTests/Core/CMakeFiles/UnitTestCore.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
[ 56%] Built target BornAgainGUI_autogen
make: *** [Makefile:166: all] Error 2
```

This is running `make -j4`, I've tried using a different amount of cores as well (as I've got eight available) but they basically end up with the same result. I think the Cmake configuration my be helpful here as well. All details regarding dependencies are given when running cmake, here's that output:

```
[sjoerd@lennart BABuild]$ cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/home/sjoerd/.BornAgain /home/sjoerd/BA/bornagain
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 11.2.1
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 11.2.1
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/lib64/ccache/cc - skipped
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/lib64/ccache/c++ - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Destination directories:
    bin->bin,
    lib->lib/BornAgain-1.19,
    gui->lib/BornAgain-1.19,
    include->include/BornAgain-1.19,
    share->share/BornAgain-1.19/,
    examples->share/BornAgain-1.19/Examples,
    images->share/BornAgain-1.19/Images,
    libexec->lib/BornAgain-1.19
-- Found a 64bit system
-- CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE: Release
-- Looking for pthread.h
-- Looking for pthread.h - found
-- Performing Test CMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_PTHREAD
-- Performing Test CMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_PTHREAD - Failed
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads - not found
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthread
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthread - found
-- Found Threads: TRUE  
-- BornAgain Platform: linux
-- BornAgain Architecture: linuxx8664
-- Build Type: Release
-- Compiler Flags:  -I/home/sjoerd/BA/bornagain/Wrap -pipe -m64 -Wall -W -Woverloaded-virtual -Wno-unknown-pragmas -fPIC -O3
-- Shared linker Flags: -Wl,--no-undefined
-- Exe linker Flags: 
-- Found FFTW3: /usr/lib64/libfftw3.so  
-- Found FFTW3: includes at /usr/include, libraries at /usr/lib64/libfftw3.so
-- Found PkgConfig: /usr/bin/pkg-config (found version "1.7.3") 
-- Found GSL: /usr/include (found version "2.6") 
-- GSL found=TRUE libs=/usr/lib64/libgsl.so;/usr/lib64/libgslcblas.so inc=/usr/include version=2.6
-- Eigen3 include_dir=/usr/include/eigen3 version=3.3.9
-- Found Cerf: /usr/lib64/libcerf.so (found version "1.14") 
-- Found libcerf, language=C, version=1.14, lib=/usr/lib64/libcerf.so, include_dir=/usr/include.
-- Search function cerf in /usr/lib64/libcerf.so ...
-- Search function cerf in /usr/lib64/libcerf.so -- found
-- Search function dawson in /usr/lib64/libcerf.so ...
-- Search function dawson in /usr/lib64/libcerf.so -- found
-- Search function voigt in /usr/lib64/libcerf.so ...
-- Search function voigt in /usr/lib64/libcerf.so -- found
-- Found Boost: /usr/include (found suitable version "1.75.0", minimum required is "1.65.1") found components: iostreams program_options regex 
-- Boost: includes at /usr/include, libraries at /usr/lib64
-- Looking for libtiff (use -DBORNAGAIN_TIFF_SUPPORT=OFF to disable)
-- Found TIFF: /usr/lib64/libtiff.so (found suitable version "4.2.0", minimum required is "4.0.2") found components: CXX 
-- Found Python3: /usr/bin/python3.9 (found version "3.9.6") found components: Interpreter Development Development.Module Development.Embed 
--   Python3_VERSION              : 3.9.6
--   Python3_INTERPRETER_ID       : Python
--   Python3_EXECUTABLE           : /usr/bin/python3.9
--   Python3_STDLIB               : /usr/lib64/python3.9 Python3_STDARCH: /usr/lib64/python3.9
--   Python3_SITELIB              : /usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages Python3_SITEARCH: /usr/lib64/python3.9/site-packages
--   Python3_INCLUDE_DIRS         : /usr/include/python3.9
--   Python3_LIBRARIES            : /usr/lib64/libpython3.9.so
--   Python3_LIBRARY_DIRS         : /usr/lib64
-- Found Python3: /usr/bin/python3.9 (found version "3.9.6") found components: Interpreter 
-- Found Python3: /usr/bin/python3.9 (found version "3.9.6") found components: Interpreter Development Development.Module Development.Embed 
-- Found Python3: /usr/bin/python3.9 (found version "3.9.6") found components: Interpreter Development NumPy Development.Module Development.Embed 
--   Python3_NumPy_VERSION        : 1.21.2
--   Python3_NumPy_INCLUDE_DIRS   : /home/sjoerd/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/core/include
-- Found OpenGL: /usr/lib64/libOpenGL.so   
-- Found Qt5 version 5.15.2
--   Qt5::Widgets /usr/lib64/libQt5Widgets.so.5.15.2
--   Qt5::Core /usr/lib64/libQt5Core.so.5.15.2
--   Qt5::Gui /usr/lib64/libQt5Gui.so.5.15.2
--   Qt5::OpenGL /usr/lib64/libQt5OpenGL.so.5.15.2
--   Includes: /usr/include/qt5/;/usr/include/qt5/QtWidgets;/usr/include/qt5/QtGui;/usr/include/qt5/QtCore;/usr/lib64/qt5//mkspecs/linux-g++
-- SwigLib Fit: BornAgainFit /home/sjoerd/BABuild/Fit/Wrap
CMake Deprecation Warning at ThirdParty/common/gtest/gtest-1.10.0/CMakeLists.txt:4 (cmake_minimum_required):
  Compatibility with CMake < 2.8.12 will be removed from a future version of
  CMake.

  Update the VERSION argument <min> value or use a ...<max> suffix to tell
  CMake that the project does not need compatibility with older versions.


CMake Deprecation Warning at ThirdParty/common/gtest/gtest-1.10.0/googlemock/CMakeLists.txt:45 (cmake_minimum_required):
  Compatibility with CMake < 2.8.12 will be removed from a future version of
  CMake.

  Update the VERSION argument <min> value or use a ...<max> suffix to tell
  CMake that the project does not need compatibility with older versions.


CMake Deprecation Warning at ThirdParty/common/gtest/gtest-1.10.0/googletest/CMakeLists.txt:56 (cmake_minimum_required):
  Compatibility with CMake < 2.8.12 will be removed from a future version of
  CMake.

  Update the VERSION argument <min> value or use a ...<max> suffix to tell
  CMake that the project does not need compatibility with older versions.


-- Found PythonInterp: /usr/bin/python (found version "3.9.6") 
-- SwigLib Base: BornAgainBase /home/sjoerd/BABuild/Base/Wrap
-- SwigLib Param: BornAgainParam /home/sjoerd/BABuild/Param/Wrap
-- SwigLib Sample: BornAgainSample /home/sjoerd/BABuild/Sample/Wrap
-- SwigLib Device: BornAgainDevice /home/sjoerd/BABuild/Device/Wrap
-- SwigLib Core: BornAgainCore /home/sjoerd/BABuild/Core/Wrap
-- Configuring BornAgain GUI
-- Installer name: BornAgain-1.19.0-linuxx8664
-- Source package name: BornAgain-1.19.0
-- CMake done
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/sjoerd/BABuild
```

I am not sure if this is an issue in my setup, but it's basically something that showed up when I upgraded to Fedora 34 (using a clean install). Any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: [std::size_t](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/size_t) is defined in a variety of headers. I'm used to the fact that it's often available as `size_t` (in global scope, probably due to the fact that the C standard library is involved somehow, and nothing you can rely on) but in C++, it should be in the `std` namespace. However, you may try two fixes: 1st: change `size_t` into `std::size_t`, 2nd: include one of the headers mentioned in the link, e.g. `#include <cstddef>`.

Comment: Thank you, that is very helpful! I am quite inexperienced with C, so I had some troubles determining how/where to include headers. I thought I maybe would need to simply add the `#include` line in my makefile, but that file directly starts with the warning '# CMAKE generated file: DO NOT EDIT!'. 

Should I include these headers somewhere else?

Comment: You have to write the `#include <cstddef>` into the file where the error is reported for. There are probably already other `#include`s. Alternatively, you should consider to report a bug where you downloaded your application. The author of this S/W might be interested as well. Maybe, he does the fix for you... (And, btw. it's C++. C doesn't have `template`s.) ;-)

Comment: Of course, that makes sense. I've actually reported it at the GitLab page of the application, and the dev told me that it's most likely because I'm using gcc 11 which has not been tested. They advised me to insert `#include <stddef.h>`  which is basically the same solution you proposed.

Indeed, including it at the file mentioned in the error gave me a completely successful compilation. Thank you so much for the help!

Comment: Fur future readers, see also https://jugit.fz-juelich.de/mlz/bornagain/-/issues/115

Answer (score 0):

Inserting #include <stddef.h> at the file where of the error appeared solved the issue. Thanks for the help!